# take an image url, apply transformation, save to folder

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a script to take a list of images (url), I want to apply a function findexts() , then get the height and width of the image and save it to folder.  I have shorten my code here... I can't get the image in a file to process.

```
function findexts ($filename) 
{ 
$filename = strtolower($filename) ; 
$exts = preg_split("%[/\\\\.]%", $filename);
$n = count($exts)-1; 
$exts = $exts[$n]; 
return $exts; 
}
```

// I have more code to get my data.. then

```
foreach ($matches as $match) {

    // $match[1] = a URL like http://www.....jpg
    // $match[2] = my blog_id

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $match[1]); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if(mime_content_type ($data) == "image/jpeg")
    { $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($data); }
    elseif(mime_content_type ($data) == "image/png")
    { $img = imagecreatefrompng($data); }
    elseif(mime_content_type ($data) == "image/gif")
    { $img = imagecreatefromgif($data); }



    //create random file name with proper extention.
    $ext = findexts ($img) ; 
    $ran = rand () ;
    $ran2 = $ran.".";
    $sourcefilename = $ran2.$ext; 


    //get width and height of original image
    $width = imagesx($img); 
    $height = imagesy($img);

    echo "width=".$width." height=".$height." filename=".$sourcefilename."<br>";

}
```

I get :
    Warning: mime_content_type(ÿØÿà) [function.mime-content-type]: failed to open stream:

and
    Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource

obviously my $img  is wrong...

Comment: try with a simple image ( preferably  `.jpg` ) with only `latin` characters in the name..

Answer (score 1):

you can use [GetImageSize](http://php.net/manual/es/function.getimagesize.php) to check extension, height and width of an image, check:

```
$imagen="lol.jpg";   //an jpg image 300x100
$condicion = GetImageSize($imagen); 
echo $condicion[0]."<br>";
echo $condicion[1]."<br>";
echo $condicion[2]."<br>";
```

will echo:

```
300
100
2 -> jpg
```

`$condicion[2]` is the extension of the image in number:

1 = GIF, 2 = JPG, 3 = PNG, 4 = SWF, 5 = PSD, 6 = BMP, 7 = TIFF(orden de bytes intel), 
8 = TIFF(orden de bytes motorola), 9 = JPC, 10 = JP2, 11 = JPX, 12 = JB2, 13 = SWC, 
14 = IFF, 15 = WBMP, 16 = XBM.

this may help you

```
$match[1]="http://s5.mangareader.net/cover/the-breaker-new-waves/the-breaker-new-waves-m0.jpg";

    $data_image = GetImageSize($match[1]); 

        if($data_image[2] == 1){ // gif
        $img = imagecreatefromgif("$match[1]");
        $ext=".gif";
        }
        if($data_image[2] == 2){ //jpg
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg("$match[1]");
        $ext=".jpg";
        }
        if($data_image[2] == 3){ //  png
        $img = imagecreatefrompng("$match[1]"); 
        $ext=".png";
        }

    //create random file name with proper extention.
        $ran = rand () ;
        $sourcefilename = $ran.$ext; 

    //get width and height of original image
    $width = $data_image[0]; 
    $height = $data_image[1];

    echo "width=".$width." height=".$height." filename=".$sourcefilename."<br>";
```